# Vim Error Command Mode

Tags: vim

Sometimes i stumble aganist this werid vim error in command mode, I am pretty sure that is caused by some of my new and werid vimrc customization..

[image]

Comment: Without a possibility to inspect your _new and werid vimrc customization_, all I can say is: That's funny!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmap` is tricky: `h` will insert `tab` (with a space) then the following `h` (in `help`) will be expanded to `tab` then `h` will be expanded to…

This is a basic recursion problem.

I suggest you use a normal mode mapping instead.